# Why d3.domain() has only one element when I use the whole data array as domain?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have done something more complicated before using `d3.histogram` and `bins`, but in the following situation, I am not sure why the `domain()` would not give back the array but only the first element? Can't we use the data array and each element in it as the "key" for the domain?

```js
const data = [
  { name: "A", value: 1 },
  { name: "B", value: 5 },
  { name: "C", value: 7 },
  { name: "D", value: 3 },
  { name: "E", value: 9 },
];

const scaleX = d3
  .scaleBand()
  .domain(data)
  .range([0, 1000]);

console.log("scaleX.domain()", scaleX.domain());
console.log("scaleX.range()", scaleX.range());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.6.2/d3.js" integrity="sha512-6G9G63qZLxEcLqVyklArI/2ZgWK1HdKMU9yWbQUJC/eSsLsaY0NZKv4JDW4ltw1Z9sEvFB3DP54GzOIkIJjyLg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Try `.domain(data.map(k => k.name))`

Comment: yeah that would work... but I just want to use an array of objects as the key, like how I did it before with `d3.histogram()` and `bins`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did it right when you passed an *array* to the `domain()` method...

```
.domain(data)
```

...however, that's not enough: arrays can contain numbers, strings, functions, other arrays etc. The problem with a band (or ordinal) scale is that you cannot have *objects* as the individual elements of the array. We can see why by having a look at the [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/8afe6bd4af7a1f0be6b4d231126bdc8a83659ab5/src/ordinal.js#L20):

```
scale.domain = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return domain.slice();
    domain = [], index = new Map();
    for (const value of _) {
      const key = value + "";
      if (index.has(key)) continue;
      index.set(key, domain.push(value));
    }
    return scale;
};
```

If you have a look at `for (const value of _) { const key = value + "";`, which internally generate the **unique** keys for a JavaScript Map, you'll see that this simply won't work for objects:

```js
const obj1 = {foo:42};
const obj2 = {bar:17};
console.log(obj1 + "");
console.log(obj2 + "");
console.log(obj1 + "" === obj2 + "");
```

The most important information in the snippet above is the `true` in the last `console.log`: all objects, even if different, become the same thing for the scale when it generates the keys for the Map (remember, band scales **cannot** have duplicated values).

Because of that, the `continue` here...

```
if (index.has(key)) continue;
```

...will always happen, so your domain effectively has just *one* element.

Comment: interesting... with `d3.histogram()`, I did get a `bins` using `bins = histogram(data);`, and I used it as `d3.scaleBand().domain(bins)` and it worked well... `bins` is also an array of objects too... ok... maybe it was due to `toString()` or `valueOf()` of `bins` being defined to return distinguishable strings... but I just tried and it didn't

Comment: @StefanieGauss the reason is that for the histogram you're probably using a value accessor. Look for `value()` in your code.

Comment: yes... that one had `let histogram = d3.histogram().value(xSelector) .domain(scaleX.domain()).thresholds(scaleX.ticks(50));` so can't I do the same with my data array in the original question?

Comment: @StefanieGauss No, you can't. That `xSelector` is probably a function that returns a given property, say `foo`, so effectively the source code in your histogram generator is doing the same of `data.map(d => d.foo)`, as explained in the [comment below your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001764/why-d3-domain-has-only-one-element-when-i-use-the-whole-data-array-as-domain/67002462?noredirect=1#comment118433862_67001764).

Comment: so it looks like we don't have `d3.scaleBand().domain(data).range([0, 1000]).value(xSelector)` to make the `xSelector` pick the key for us, but then we have to use `d3.scaleBand().domain(data.map(xSelector)).range([0, 1000])`